# Prevent text from being selected on mobile unless directly touching it?

Tags: javascript, html

On mobile, if you press and hold your finger on a screen, then text on the screen will get selected even if it is far away.

I could disable this behavior by using `user-select: none`, but ideally I would want the user to be able to select the text if they are directly pressing their finger on it.

Is this possible?

It looks like `user-select: contain` could solve the issue, but this is not implemented in many / most browsers.